# Codewars Challenge - Count of positives / sum of negatives

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

My code works but it's not being accepted in order to pass the challenge. Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

**Challenge Description:**

Given an array of integers.
Return an array, where the first element is the count of positives numbers and the second element is sum of negative numbers.
If the input array is empty or null, return an empty array:

```
C#/Java: new int[] {} / new int[0];
C++: std::vector<int>();
JavaScript/CoffeeScript/PHP/Haskell: [];
Rust: Vec::<i32>::new();
```

ATTENTION!
The passed array should NOT be changed. Read more here.*

**For example:**

**input** [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15]

**return** [10, -65].

**My Code:**

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {

if (input.length < 1){
  return [];
}

var newArray = [0, 0];


for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){

  if (input[i] > 0)
    {
    newArray[0] += 1;
    }

  else {
    newArray[1] += input[i];
  }

  }
return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not checking for `null` when the challenge explicitly  requires that "if the input array is empty or null, return an empty array". Please consider changing the code as follows

```
if (input == null || input.length < 1){
  return [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for me (in JavaScript)

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
    if (input === null || input.length < 1) {
        return [];
    }
    var array = [0, 0];

    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if(input[i] <= 0) {
            array[1] += input[i];
      } else {
            array[0] += 1;
      }
    }
    return array;
}
```

So, you need check if input === null (and return empty array), and if input[i] <= 0 (to sum of negatives)

Answer (score 1):

> **This one definitely works ::**

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
let positiveNums = 0;
// initialize positive number variable
let negativeNums = 0;
// initialize negative number variable

if (input === null || input.length === 0) {
  return []; // if the input is empty or null, it will return empty array
} else {
  input.forEach((num) => num > 0 ? positiveNums++ : negativeNums += num);
}
return [positiveNums , negativeNums];}
```

**For positive numbers, it will add the current number to the previous number and return the latest available value after iterating through the whole array.**

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code - it is very hard to understand something when it isn't explained.

Comment: @ethry, It's commented for better readability now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach I used in Javascript so maybe you can borrow afew ideas off it as well

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
if (input == null || input.length < 1){
  return [];
}
var sum =0;
var pos =[];

for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++){

if(input[i]>0){
pos.push(input[i]);

} else{
sum += input[i];

}
}
    return [pos.length, sum];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for this task:

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
  let sumOfPositive = 0;  
  let sumOfNegative = 0; 
  
  if(input == null || input.length < 1) {
    return [];
    } else {
      input.map(item => {
        if(item > 0) {
          sumOfPositive++;
        } else if(item < 0) {
          sumOfNegative += item;
        } else {
          return []
        }
      })
    }
  return [sumOfPositive, sumOfNegative]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for this task:

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives (a) {
  if (!a || !a.length) return []

  let pos = a.filter(x => x > 0),
      neg = a.filter(x => x <= 0)

  return [pos.length, Math.floor(neg.reduce((s,v)=>s+v,0))]
}
```

[solution for codewars](https://irenoo.com/question/count-of-positives-sum-of-negatives-js/)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Meet the longest code in the topic

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
    if (input && input.length > 1) {
      let count = [];
      let sum = [];
      for (i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] > 0) {
          count.push(input[i]);
        } if (input[i] < 0) {
          sum.push(input[i]);
        }
      };
      let sumNegatives = 0
      for (i=0; i<sum.length; i++) {
        sumNegatives += sum[i];
      }
      let result = [count.length, sumNegatives];
      return result;
    };
    if (input === null || input.length < 1) {
      let result = [];
      return result;
    };
    if (input[0] < 0) {
      let result = [0, input[0]]
      return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
const pos = input.filter((el) => el >= 1).length;
const neg = input.filter((el) => el < 0);
const negSums = neg.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

(input === null || input.length == 0) ? [] : (input.forEach((num) => num > 0 ? pos : []))

const finalArr = [];
finalArr.push(negSums);
finalArr.unshift(pos);
return finalArr;
```

}

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code - it is very hard to understand something when it isn't explained.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
let pos = []
let neg = []
if (input === null || !input.length) return []
else {
    input.map(num => {
        return num > 0 ? pos.push(num) : neg.push(num)
    })
}
let out1 = pos.length
let out2 = neg.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
return [out1, out2]
```

}